# Python BS4 getting all unembedded `li`

Tags: python, html, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to grab only the first `li` items on each column, but I either get everything on the page within the `div` or on the first in each column.

I've tried setting `recursive=False` but that's only let to getting the first in each column.

https://exrx.net/Lists/Directory - link to the site I'm using for this.

My goal with that is to grab the `href` of Shoulders, Neck, Chest, etc, without any of the children under it. I'm looking for those specifically as anything under it is repetitive and is leading me to the same general page. This is the code I currently have.

```
cut_url = "https://exrx.net/Lists/"

exrx = []


for a in soup.findAll('div', class_='col-sm-6'):
    for li in a.find_all('ul'):
        a = li.find('a')
        url = cut_url + a['href']
        exrx.append(url)
```

Comment: You can use `soup.select("div>ul>li>a")` to select all the top level links and iterate over the result to get their `href` attribute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "https://exrx.net/Lists/Directory"
soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).content, "html.parser")

for a in soup.select("article li:has(>ul) > a"):
    print(
        a.text,
        "https://exrx.net/Lists/" + a["href"]
        if "https" not in a["href"]
        else a["href"],
    )
```

Prints:

```
Neck https://exrx.net/Lists/ExList/NeckWt
Shoulders https://exrx.net/Lists/ExList/ShouldWt
Upper Arms https://exrx.net/Lists/ExList/ArmWt
Forearms https://exrx.net/Lists/ExList/ForeArmWt
Back https://exrx.net/Lists/ExList/BackWt
Chest https://exrx.net/Lists/ExList/ChestWt
Waist https://exrx.net/Lists/ExList/WaistWt
Hips https://exrx.net/Lists/ExList/HipsWt
Thighs https://exrx.net/Lists/ExList/ThighWt
Calves https://exrx.net/Lists/ExList/CalfWt
```